# issu related with importing ion-auth sql file

Tags: mysql, postgresql, codeigniter, ion-auth

When I tried to import ion_auth.postgre.sql file from ion auth folder. I got the following error. how to fix it.

Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE "users"(
"id"SERIAL NOT NULL ,
"ip_address"varchar( 15 ) ,
"username"varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
"password"varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
"salt"varchar( 255 ) ,
"email"varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
"activation_code"varchar( 40 ) ,
"forgotten_password_code"varchar( 40 ) ,
"forgotten_password_time"int,
"remember_code"varchar( 40 ) ,
"created_on"int NOT NULL ,
"last_login"int,
"active"int4,
"first_name"varchar( 50 ) ,
"last_name"varchar( 50 ) ,
"company"varchar( 100 ) ,
"phone"varchar( 20 ) ,
PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ) ,
CONSTRAINT "check_id" CHECK (
id >=0
),
CONSTRAINT "check_active" CHECK (
active >=0
)
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

> near '"users" (
>       "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
>       "ip_address" varchar(15),
>       "userna' at line 1

Comment: Your question is not clearly understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have MySQL server set up and you are importing postgreSQL

please see numero 3. in the [manual](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)

> Run the appropriate SQL file from the /sql directory.

**Solution:** Import MySQL file instead.